# How to count a join in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables,

Cities

```
Id | city_name
```

Wanteds

```
Id | city_id | user_id
```

I want to create a table using a MySQL query that looks like the following -

```
City Name | Number of Wanteds
Leeds     | 3
Manchester| 1
Halifax   | 0
Bradford  | 0
```

etc

where the Number of wanteds pull from the Wanteds table the total number of city_id's.

I have tried

```
select c.city_name, count(w.city_id) from cities c inner join wanteds w on c.id = w.city_id
```

but it only returns the total count for the first city.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add group by clause

```
  select c.city_name, count(w.city_id) 
  from cities c inner join wanteds w on c.id = w.city_id
  group by c.city_name
```